# Joining two tables, one with identical unique rows and the other one with multiple corresponding rows

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, rdbms

I have two tables one of which holds person and parcel information. Every row in this table is unique. There is no repetitve data. It is something as follows;

[image]

Additionally, I have this table which includes explanations for these unique rows shown above. For instance

[image]

As you can see there are 3 different explanations for just "Jane". I want to add explanation1, explanation2, explanation3 columns to the first table and update those fields with the corresponding information from the second table.

However, the problem emerges exactly at that point. When I select lets say Name, Surname, Parcel and Block fields from both tables to match, all the explanation columns which need to be updated with the relevant explanations are being filled with just with the first explanation. As an example, all the explanation1,explanation2,explanation3 fields for "Jane Black" in the first row of the first table are updated with only "Lorem ipsum dolor sit". The remaining explanations from the second table remains unused.

To sum up, I wonder, is the way I approach the problem not reasonable or is there a way to solve this issue following my approach?
(I utilize both access, mysql as RDBMS etc.)

Comment: Why do you want to add 3 columns to the first table?  What happens when you get a situation where there are 4 explanations, will you add a 4th column?  It appears to me that the change you want to make is a regression, not an improvement *(You'll denormalise the data, when in general you should normalise the data)*.  My advice is to Not do what you're suggesting.

Comment: In Oracle, I would use LISTAGG function to concatenate the explanation of same Name/Surname. Then I would join this result to your main table. 
See if you have any way/substitute of LISTAGG function in ms-access.

Comment: `select Name, Surname, Parcel and Block, group_concat(explanation) from table2 group by No, Name, Surname`

Comment: @MatBailie I know the max. number of explanations to be added for all rows. That's why I created 14 new explanation columns alongside "date of explanation" columns although I did not mention in my question. So concatenating the explanations into one cell for each person does not seem to be a reasonable solution. I want to utilize each of these explanations indvivually. That's why each explanation and date should be in a single cell in the same row.

Comment: @Sam - You're still denormalising your data-structure in to a worse one.  You've said `what` you want to do, but not `why` you want to do it.  This request is a code-smell; what ever you want to do with your re-structured data can *very* likely be done better in a different way using the existing normalised structure.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a nasty way to do it and not tested.

This uses 3 sub queries that get the required explanations for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd explanation columns:-

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.parcel, t1.block, t1.share, t1.id, t2a.explanation, t2b.explanation, t2c.explanation
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    FROM table2 t21
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t22
    ON t21.name = t22.name AND t21.surname = t22.surname AND t21.parcel = t22.parcel AND t21.block = t22.block AND t21.share = t22.share AND t21.id = t22.id AND t1.o > t2.no
    GROUP BY t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    HAVING COUNT(t22.No) = 0
) t2a ON t1.name = t2a.name AND t2.surname = t2a.surname AND t1.parcel = t2a.parcel AND t1.block = t2a.block AND t1.share = t2a.share AND t1.id = t2a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    FROM table2 t21
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t22
    ON t21.name = t22.name AND t21.surname = t22.surname AND t21.parcel = t22.parcel AND t21.block = t22.block AND t21.share = t22.share AND t21.id = t22.id AND t1.o > t2.no
    GROUP BY t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    HAVING COUNT(t22.No) = 0
) t2b ON t1.name = t2b.name AND t2.surname = t2b.surname AND t1.parcel = t2b.parcel AND t1.block = t2b.block AND t1.share = t2b.share AND t1.id = t2b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    FROM table2 t21
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t22
    ON t21.name = t22.name AND t21.surname = t22.surname AND t21.parcel = t22.parcel AND t21.block = t22.block AND t21.share = t22.share AND t21.id = t22.id AND t1.o > t2.no
    GROUP BY t21.name, t21.parcel, t21.block, t21.share, t21.id, t21.explanation
    HAVING COUNT(t22.No) = 0
) t2c ON t1.name = t2c.name AND t2.surname = t2c.surname AND t1.parcel = t2c.parcel AND t1.block = t2c.block AND t1.share = t2c.share AND t1.id = t2c.id
```

Simpler but a bit less reliable is the use GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX. This get a string of all the explanations separated with a random string (I have used ~#~##~ here), then splitting that up picking a different one for each column. This will of course fail if an explanation happens to contain the string you use to delimit it.

```
SELECT t1.name, 
        t1.parcel, 
        t1.block, 
        t1.share, 
        t1.id, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.explanation ORDER BY t2.no SEPARATOR '~#~#~'), '~#~#~', 1),
        IF(COUNT(t2.no) >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.explanation ORDER BY t2.no SEPARATOR '~#~#~'), '~#~#~', 1), '~#~#~', -1), NULL),
        IF(COUNT(t2.no) >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.explanation ORDER BY t2.no SEPARATOR '~#~#~'), '~#~#~', 2), '~#~#~', -1), NULL)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.surname = t2.surname AND t1.parcel = t2.parcel AND t1.block = t2.block AND t1.share = t2.share AND t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.name, 
        t1.parcel, 
        t1.block, 
        t1.share, 
        t1.id
```

But personally I would probably do this in code outside SQL.